# Problem with internal linking on homepage

Tags: wordpress, helper

Currently trying to learn wordpress after doing a bit of html Css and I've kind of hit a problem with the internal linking on my website.

https:www.burglaralarminstallers.com

Basically when I do sitechecker seo I'm getting 3xx errors on the internal links from my homepage to the  the other 2 pages on my site.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to solve this as I've spent days googling and cannot sort it.

This is the .htaccess in the root folder

```
# BEGIN GD-SSL 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
  Options +FollowSymLinks RewriteEngine 
  On RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on 
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(.+)$ 
  RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^www\.burglaralarminstallers\.com$ 
  RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L] 
  Header add Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=300" 
</IfModule> 
# END GD-SSL 
# BEGIN WordPress 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
   RewriteEngine On 
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] 
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
   RewriteRule . /index.php [L] 
</IfModule> 
# END WordPress 
# BEGIN ShortPixelWebp # END ShortPixelWebp 
# Wordfence WAF 
<Files ".user.ini"> 
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c> 
  Require all denied 
</IfModule> 
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c> 
   Order deny,allow Deny from all 
</IfModule> 
</Files>
```

Thank you

Comment: https://sitechecker.pro/seo-report/https://www.burglaralarminstallers.com

Comment: Can you share your .htaccess file in the wordpress root folder?

Comment: I'll have to upload it when I get home as I have it on my desktop

Comment: Add this .htaccess content to the question by editing the question